# Why cant i load the image in picasso?

Tags: android, picasso

The actual code is very simple like this but doesnt works!!

```
        File f = new File("file://E:/test.jpeg");

       Picasso.with(this).load(f).
            into(avatar);
```

Comment: Is there a stacktrace ? Or does it simply not display the image ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We can help you more quickly if you take the time to provide more detail in your question. First of all, create a new project in Android Studio and add enough code to it to recreate the problem you are asking about. See [mcve] for tips on creating a good code example. Second, be sure to include a description of what your example code does and tell us how this differs from what you want. If you take the time to do both of these, you will get your answer in a much more timely manner.

Comment: file://E:/test.jpeg. Is that on your device? or computer?

Comment: computer...working on localhost

Comment: when you are testing something on your device within localhost...localhost is your device.... not your computer.

Answer (score 1):

```
File f = new File("file://E:/test.jpeg");
```

First, Android does not have drive letters, let alone an `E:` drive. That is not a valid filesystem path to any file on any Android device.

Second, the `File` constructor takes a filesystem path, not a `Uri` with a scheme (e.g., `file://`).

Answer (score 1):

Its important to know that the file you are accessing has to be on your DEVICE and NOT from your computer. There is no such directory as a E: drive on phones.

You have a few options. Store the image online, and load it with Picasso (the easiest).

```
Picasso.with(getActivity())
            .load("http://www.image_url.com/image.png")
            .into(avatar);
```

Or, you can get the file path of an image, and then use that with picasso.

```
File file = new File("path-to-image/image.png")
Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(file).into(avatar);
```

How do you get the path-to-image of an image on your device?

You can follow this http://www.limbaniandroid.com/2014/03/how-to-get-absolute-path-when-select.html